# is there any method in java which does the same thing as Streamreader() in c++?

Tags: java, visual-c++

Is there any method in java which does the same thing as `Streamreader()` in VC++ ? Also, any methods to implement the functions of `seek()`, `seekorigin()` as implemented in VC++?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps BufferedReader is what you want.

If you want random seek access I would just use a String rather than a stream.

Answer (score 0):

For searching capabilities, have a look at [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 0):

For StreamReader, below is the example mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) translated to java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream("TestFile.txt")));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (input != null) { input.close(); };
        }
    }
}
```

As for seek and seekorigin, take a look at [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to see if it does what you want.